# How do I more thoroughly access Android sensors?

Tags: java, android, proximity

I am trying to access the sensors (proximity and RGBW sensors specifically) on my Samsung Galaxy S3 and have gotten a code to run to access the proximity sensors. However, I am only getting the values 1 or 8 (near/far). I am aware that sometimes the hardware can only access a near/far reading, but by using Samsung's *#0*# code and doing sensor testing, I was able to see ADC readings from the proximity sensor which showed relative distance measurements and RGBW values. I was wondering if there was anything I could do to access those values in an Android app.

In summary, is there any way I can access ADC values of the proximity sensor through an Android app? Is there a code in the Google API which allows me to access RGBW sensors, which are pretty new and not usually used by developers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> In summary, is there any way I can access ADC values of the proximity sensor through an Android app?

Not via the Android SDK using known `Sensor` types. Certain device manufacturers might offer SDK add-ons for that, though I am not aware of any. Or, a device manufacturer might support some alternative `Sensor` type name for that, though again I am not aware of any.